# If Statement Not Executing First Print Command, Fibonacci Assignment

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm a complete newbie to Python, but trying to write a simple program here and cannot figure out why my first "if" statement is not executing (from what I can tell).

I have the following:

```
fibo=[1,1]

num = int(input('Length of Fibonacci Sequence:'))
iterate = num - 2

for i in range (iterate):
    if num < 2 :
        print ('Length must be > 2')

    else:
        fibo.append(fibo[-1]+fibo[-2])

print ('The Fibonacci Sequence for the first', num, 'integers is:')
print (fibo)
```

It works exactly like I would hope for any input above 2.  If I enter anything below 2, I would expect it to print "Length must be >2" but instead get no output at all.

I would appreciate any help!  Thank you!

Comment: Less than 2 will give `for i in range(-<some_value>)` which doesn't do anything. That's why you aren't seeing anything execute:
`list(range(-1))` becomes
`[]`

Comment: Thank you so much!  You got me through my complete mental block!  I've rearranged things now and it's working great!

Comment: A great tool to identify these kind of problems are debuggers or the [online tool PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Answer (score 0):

If your input is less than 2, then iterate will be less than or equal to 0. The for loop will never execute because of this. You could move your if statement outside of the loop to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `for` statement is not being executed.

```
fibo = [1, 1]

num = 0 # int(input('Length of Fibonacci Sequence:'))
iterate = num - 2

for i in range (iterate): # here, interate is 0.
    # this is not executed
    if num < 2:
        print('Length must be > 2')
    else:
        fibo.append(fibo[-1]+fibo[-2])

print('The Fibonacci Sequence for the first', num, 'integers is:')
print(fibo)
```

Just do

```
fibo = [1, 1]

def nextFib(num):
    iterate = num - 2

    if num < 2:
        print('Length must be > 2')    
    else:
        for i in range (iterate):
            fibo.append(fibo[-1]+fibo[-2])

print('The Fibonacci Sequence for the first', num, 'integers is:')
print(fibo)
```